# Objective-C Detect a viewDidAppear from 'Back' button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I currently have a UIViewController "Radio" with a button on it.

When the button is clicked, the "Radio" viewcontroller pushes another UIViewController called "details"

When the user hits "Back" and returns back to the "Radio" view controller, I need a method to detect that it did so, to prevent refreshing the View.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

In the Radio class:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
}
```